# Try - Catch Result Placement in View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a try-catch block in my code.  It looks similar to this:

```
try
{
   return OK(await _service.GetInformation(string ID));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, ex.GetExceptionDetails()));
   return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
}
```

I would like if this fails (it is part of a search) to put the exception on the view as an error

I would like to know how to "print out" the exception.  I know using ex.message(); in a console.writeline command will do it but that doesn't seem to in this case.

Perhaps it would be better to create a custom error page to do this.  If that is the case then please let me know as that would change the dynamics of what I am working on.

I have tried using the Console.Writeline(ex.message) and that did not work at all. Honestly, I didn't expect it to work.

When I tried to do that it made it so the original message, which is supposed to appear in conjunction with the exception, did not appear, what I was expecting was the original message to appear on the left side and the new exception message to appear on the right side.

The original message is "No data found with the parameters given" and is displayed in the .cshtml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TempData` to store the error message:

```
public IActionResult MethodName()
{
try 
{
   return OK(await _service.GetInformation(string ID));
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   TempData["error"] = ex.Message;
   return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
}
}
```

Then display it in your View by using the following code:

```
@TempData["error"]
```

Comment: this is a perfect solution for what I need.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print it somewhere and the Console doesn't seem to work, you can try showing it to your application. If you just want to view what the exception message is, debug and and make a breakpoint in the next command inside the catch exception and when it hits the breakpoint view the content of ex and let your mouse above x instance (If you are using VSCode with the right extensions or if you are using Visual Studio.

If you need to print ex.Message in the Console then try this inside the catch (Exception ex)

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   _logger.Log(LogLevel.Critical, ex.GetExceptionDetails());
   // Print the exception details to the console
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Message: " + ex.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Exception Type: " + ex.GetType().FullName);
    return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
}
```

Comment: about your _logger is assume thaat is an instance of a logging framework like Serilog, NLog, or the built-in ILogger, and ex.GetExceptionDetails() returns a string containing the exception details, this code should work to log the exception at the LogLevel.Critical.

Just make sure that your _logger is properly configured and integrated into your application to capture and store log entries according to your logging requirements.

Comment: I apologize this is not a console application.  I didn't mean to infer that, I was just trying to show what I have used so far

Comment: this would work well for a console application.  Thank you for your assistance